# How to use the case statement to call functions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi I have used this code to find the .java file from the given path and generate the list of the .java files from the path to output file,and count total number of tabs and spaces in each java file.now i need to write the two while loops in function and call that function in case statement, how to do this?

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
    #
    output=/home/user/Desktop/file-list.txt
    path=/home/user/Desktop
    find $path -type f -name \*.java > $output
    echo "Generating files list..."
    echo "Done"


    while IFS= read file
    do 
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
            spaces=$(tr -cd '\s' < "$file"  | wc -c);
            echo "$spaces spaces in file $file" >> "/home/user/Desktop/space-count.txt"
        fi
    done < "$output"
    echo "Space Count Done!"



    while IFS= read file
    do 
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
            tabs=$(tr -cd '\t' < "$file"  | wc -c);
            echo "$tabs tabs in file $file" >> "/home/user/Desktop/tab-count.txt"
        fi
    done < "$output"
    echo "Tab Count Done!"
```

Comment: Find and take a look at a few `function` examples and you'll make it. It's easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of case, but the name of the character could be passed to the function
thereby eliminating the need to case the char.

```
function count_char
{
    flist=$1
    ch=$2

    case $ch in
       " ")  chName=space;;
       "\t") chName=tab;;
    esac

    while IFS= read file
    do 
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
            tot=$(tr -cd $ch < "$file"  | wc -c);
            echo "$tot $chName in file $file" >> "/home/user/Desktop/tab-count.txt"
        fi
    done < "$flist"   
}

# setup code, find command here
# ....

count_char $output " "
count_char $output "\t"
```

Comment: Note, should use POSIX function syntax for a `#!/bin/sh` script.